# If you have multiple planeswalkers, how many of their loyalty abilities can you use in a single turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-planeswalkers

Let’s say I played [Ajani, Caller of the Pride](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAjani%2c%20Caller%20of%20the%20Pride%5d) and then played [Ajani, Wise  Counselor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=450228). Would I be able to use Caller of the Pride's -8 ability to give me, say, 20 creatures and then use Wise Counselor's +2 ability in order to gain life for each creature on the field? Would I be able to do that in the same turn or would I have to use one wait a turn then play the other?

Comment: Aren't they both Legendary Ajanis and can't be used at the same time?

Comment: @Malady, no, that was the old rule (see 306.4 in the [Comprehensive Rules](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/rules))

Answer (score 12):

> 306.5d Each planeswalker has a number of loyalty abilities, which are activated abilities with loyalty symbols in their costs. Loyalty abilities follow special rules: A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent they control any time they have priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of their turn, but only if none of that permanent’s loyalty abilities have been activated that turn. See rule 606, “Loyalty Abilities.”

The rules only say something about not activating a single planeswalker's loyalty abilities twice in a turn, not about a hard limit of one loyalty ability activation *per player*. Therefore, you can use one Ajani's ability first and then the other's ability in the same turn.

Comment: And to answer the literal question, it's possible to set up combos with arbitrarily large number of Planeswalker loyalty abilities used. For instance, if you have Aminatou, the Fateshifter and Spark Double, you can use the -1 ability on each other as many times as you want to. With Sorin, Lord of Innistrad, two Doubling Seasons, and a Spark Double, you could use Sorin's ultimate as many times as you want.